# Price number format on Smarty

Tags: php, codeigniter, css, smarty, number-formatting

I think it is a rather silly question, I researched on ways to format numbers to convert to price format. I'm using smarty as template system. Is it possible to format prices by smarty or some method that can be used for this purpose?

I need to convert the type numbers 1000000 to $1.000.000

If no output format for smarty, what other methods are there?

thanks

Comment: ${1000000|number_format:0:" ":"."}

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's [money format function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

In smarty that would be `{$myNumber|money_format:'%i'}`

Comment: function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities

Comment: This function is deprecated, don't use it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend to use Internationalization extension class `NumberFormatter`

PHP manual of function:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

PHP manual of class: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

PHP manual of extension: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Does job perfectly.

PHP code example:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'format_currency', [
            NumberFormatter::create('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY),
            'formatCurrency'
        ]);
```

Smarty template:

```
{9.1|format_currency:USD} {100.19|format_currency:EUR}
```

Output

```
$9.10 €100.19
```

Instead of 'en_US' you can use your default locale `locale_get_default()`

PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php

Answer (score 0):

use plugin for smarty 3.x

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl

Code example :

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->registerPlugin("modifier", "number_format", "number_format");
```

and in smarty tpl file you code html like this :

```
...
<td style="text-align:right;border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;">{$upah|number_format:2:",":"."}</td>
...
```

Note : "," is decimal simbol and "." is thousand sparator, you can interchange it.